# How do I pass information between two JFrames?

Tags: java, jframe

I got a JFrame game as a school project, with a button, that leads to a second JFrame, which is the settings Frame. I now want my settings to apply to my main JFrame. How do I do this?

Main JFrame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.geom.*;                                                   
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.*;

public class SpiceWars4 extends JFrame {
  // Anfang Attribute
  private JList jList1 = new JList();
  private DefaultListModel jList1Model = new DefaultListModel();                   
  private JScrollPane jList1ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList1);
  private JList jList2 = new JList();
  private DefaultListModel jList2Model = new DefaultListModel();
  private JScrollPane jList2ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList2);
  private JList jList3 = new JList();
  private DefaultListModel jList3Model = new DefaultListModel();
  private JScrollPane jList3ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList3);
  private JLabel lSchwarzmarkt = new JLabel();
  private JLabel lLaderaum = new JLabel();
  private JButton bKaufen = new JButton();
  private JButton bVerkaufen = new JButton();
  private JNumberField jNumberField1 = new JNumberField();
  private JButton bWeiterreisen = new JButton();
  public int radius;

  private JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
  private JButton jtest = new JButton();
  // Ende Attribute
  
  int [] KostenMin = new int [5]; 
  int [] KostenMax = new int [5]; 
  //**Grunddinger Anfang 
  
  int Geld, Laderaum; 
  String [] Gewürze = new String [5]; 
  int [] aktKosten = new int [5]; 
  int [] EigeneLadung = new int [5]; 
  
  Random rand = new Random(); 
  //**Grunddinger Ende                                                                  
  public SpiceWars4() { 
    // Frame-Initialisierung
    super();
    //String filepath = "song.wav"; //wählt song aus
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    int frameWidth = 865; 
    int frameHeight = 698;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("SpiceWars");
    setResizable(false);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    
    cp.setBackground(new Color(0x666666));
    // Anfang Komponenten
    
    jList1.setModel(jList1Model);
    jList1ScrollPane.setBounds(24, 48, 302, 228);
    jList1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
        jList1_MouseClicked(evt);
      }
    });
    jList1.setBackground(new Color(0x646464));
    cp.add(jList1ScrollPane);
    jList2.setModel(jList2Model);
    jList2ScrollPane.setBounds(504, 48, 278, 260);
    jList2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
        jList2_MouseClicked(evt);
      }
    });
    jList2.setBackground(new Color(0x646464));
    cp.add(jList2ScrollPane);
    jList3.setModel(jList3Model);
    jList3ScrollPane.setBounds(24, 296, 142, 220);
    jList3.setBackground(new Color(0x646464));
    cp.add(jList3ScrollPane);
    lSchwarzmarkt.setBounds(104, 8, 91, 28);
    lSchwarzmarkt.setText("Markt ");
    lSchwarzmarkt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    cp.add(lSchwarzmarkt);
    lLaderaum.setBounds(614, 8, 62, 28);
    lLaderaum.setText("Laderaum ");
    lLaderaum.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    cp.add(lLaderaum);
    bKaufen.setBounds(368, 88, 83, 33);
    bKaufen.setText(">>Kaufen ");
    bKaufen.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bKaufen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bKaufen_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    bKaufen.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) { 
        bKaufen_KeyPressed(evt);
      }
    });
    bKaufen.setBackground(new Color(0x4F9B9B));
    cp.add(bKaufen);
    bVerkaufen.setBounds(368, 136, 83, 33);
    bVerkaufen.setText("<<Verkaufen ");
    bVerkaufen.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bVerkaufen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bVerkaufen_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    bVerkaufen.setBackground(new Color(0x4F9B9B));
    cp.add(bVerkaufen);
    jNumberField1.setBounds(368, 48, 83, 28);
    jNumberField1.setText("");
    jNumberField1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    cp.add(jNumberField1);
    bWeiterreisen.setBounds(126, 570, 83, 33);
    bWeiterreisen.setText("Weiterreisen");
    bWeiterreisen.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bWeiterreisen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bWeiterreisen(evt);
      }
    });
    
    bWeiterreisen.setBackground(new Color(0x008080));
    cp.add(bWeiterreisen);
    bWeiterreisen.setBounds(96, 568, 136, 33);
    bWeiterreisen.setBounds(32, 536, 136, 33);
    jButton1.setBounds(712, 600, 112, 24);
    jButton1.setText("Einstellungen");
    jButton1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));

  
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        jButton1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.add(jButton1);
    jtest.setBounds(736, 536, 80, 24);
    jtest.setText("Button");
    jtest.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    jtest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        jtest_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.add(jtest);
    // Ende Komponenten
    
    //**Eigene Variabelen Anfang 
    Geld = 10000; 
    Laderaum = 1000 ;
    
    Gewürze[0] = "Pfeffer";
    Gewürze[1] = "Muskat";
    Gewürze[2] = "Curry";
    Gewürze[3] = "Vanille";
    Gewürze[4] = "Zimt";
    
    aktKosten[0] = 1500;
    aktKosten[1] = 5000;
    aktKosten[2] = 900;
    aktKosten[3] = 1400;
    aktKosten[4] = 650;
    
    EigeneLadung[0] = 0;
    EigeneLadung[1] = 0;
    EigeneLadung[2] = 0;
    EigeneLadung[3] = 0;
    EigeneLadung[4] = 0;
    //**Eigene Variablen Ende 
    
    //**Preisrandomisen Weiterreisen Anfang 
    KostenMin[0] = 1300;
    KostenMin[1] = 4250;
    KostenMin[2] = 725;
    KostenMin[3] = 1125;
    KostenMin[4] = 400;
    
    KostenMax[0] = 1700; 
    KostenMax[1] = 6250; 
    KostenMax[2] = 1150; 
    KostenMax[3] = 1625; 
    KostenMax[4] = 800; 
    //**Preisrandomisen Weiterreisen Ende
    
    Datenanzeigen();
    setVisible(true);
  } // end of public SpiceWars4
  
  // Anfang Methoden
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpiceWars4();                                                                          
  } // end of main
  
  //**Kaufenbutton Anfang 
  public void bKaufen_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    int Anzahl = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField1.getText());
    int Nummer = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
    if (Anzahl*aktKosten[Nummer] <= Geld) {
      Geld = Geld - Anzahl * aktKosten[Nummer]; 
      EigeneLadung[Nummer] = EigeneLadung[Nummer] + Anzahl;
    } // end of if
    Datenanzeigen();
  } // end of bKaufen_ActionPerformed
  //**Kaufenbutton Ende
  
  //**Vekaufsbutton Anfang 
  public void bVerkaufen_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    int Anzahl = Integer.parseInt(jNumberField1.getText());
    int Nummer = jList2.getSelectedIndex();
    if (Anzahl <= EigeneLadung [Nummer]) {
      Geld = Geld + Anzahl * aktKosten[Nummer]; 
      EigeneLadung[Nummer] = EigeneLadung[Nummer]-Anzahl; 
    } // end of if
    Datenanzeigen();
  } // end of bVerkaufen_ActionPerformed
  //**Vekaufsbutton Ende
  
  public void Datenanzeigen(){
    jList1Model.removeAllElements();
    jList2Model.removeAllElements();
    jList3Model.removeAllElements();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      jList1Model.addElement(Gewürze[i] + " kostet: " + aktKosten[i] + " Münzen ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      jList2Model.addElement(Gewürze[i] + " geladen: " + EigeneLadung[i] + " Stück ");
    }
    jList2Model.addElement("----------") ;
    jList2Model.addElement("Geld: " + Geld);
    
    jList3Model.addElement("Mendig");
    jList3Model.addElement("Mayen");
    jList3Model.addElement("Kruft");
    jList3Model.addElement("Thür");
    jList3Model.addElement("Bell");
    
    
    }
  public void jList1_MouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    int Index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
    jNumberField1.setText(Integer.toString((Geld / aktKosten[Index])));
  } // end of jList1_MouseClicked

  public void jList2_MouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    int Index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
    jNumberField1.setText(Integer.toString(EigeneLadung[Index]));
  } // end of jList2_MouseClicked
  
  //**weiterreisen von Welt zu Welt Anfang 
  public void bWeiterreisen(ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      aktKosten[i] = KostenMin[i] + rand.nextInt(KostenMax[i] - KostenMin[i]);
    }
    Datenanzeigen();
  } // end of bWeiterreisen_ActionPerformed
  //**Weiterreisen von Welt zu Welt Ende

  public void bKaufen_KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    
  } // end of bKaufen_KeyPressed

  public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JFrame2 jf2 = new JFrame2();  //initalisierung neues jframe
    jf2.setVisible(true);
    dispose();  //Schließt das game
 
  } // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed

  public void jtest_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   
  } // end of jtest_ActionPerformed

  // Ende Methoden
} // end of class Spielprogrammieren
```

Settings JFrame:

```
 

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.geom.*;                                                   
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.*;


public class JFrame2 extends JFrame {
  // Anfang Attribute
  private JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
  private JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();

  private JButton jmute = new JButton();
  private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
  private JButton bDarkMode1 = new JButton();
  private JButton bLightMode1 = new JButton();
  private JPanel jDifficulty = new JPanel();
  private JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
    private ButtonGroup jDifficultyBG = new ButtonGroup();
    private TitledBorder jDifficultyTB = new TitledBorder("Schwierigkeit");
    private JRadioButton jDifficultyRB0 = new JRadioButton("Schwer");
    private JRadioButton jDifficultyRB1 = new JRadioButton("Mittel");
    private JRadioButton jDifficultyRB2 = new JRadioButton("Leicht");
  // Ende Attribute
  
  public JFrame2() { 
         
    
    // Frame-Initialisierung
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    int frameWidth = 373; 
    int frameHeight = 517;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("Einstellungen");
    setResizable(false);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    
   
    cp.setLayout(null);
    cp.setBackground(new Color(0x666666));
    // Anfang Komponenten
    
    jButton1.setBounds(104, 440, 160, 24);
    jButton1.setText("Zurück");
    jButton1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        jButton1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    jButton1.setBackground(new Color(0x49969E));
    cp.add(jButton1);
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(696, -16, 1, 17);
    cp.add(jScrollPane1);
  
    jmute.setBounds(120, 160, 128, 24);
    jmute.setText("Musik aus");
    jmute.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    jmute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        jmute_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    jmute.setBackground(new Color(0x49969E));
    jmute.setRolloverEnabled(false);
    cp.add(jmute);
    jLabel1.setBounds(112, 24, 328, 47);
    jLabel1.setText("Einstellungen");
    jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 24));
    cp.add(jLabel1);


    bDarkMode1.setBounds(144, 216, 80, 24);
    bDarkMode1.setText("Dark Mode");
    bDarkMode1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bDarkMode1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bDarkMode1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    bDarkMode1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    bDarkMode1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    cp.add(bDarkMode1);
    bLightMode1.setBounds(144, 272, 80, 24);
    bLightMode1.setText("Light Mode");
    bLightMode1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    bLightMode1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        bLightMode1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    bLightMode1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    bLightMode1.setForeground(new Color(0x060606));
    cp.add(bLightMode1);
    jDifficulty.setLayout(null);
    jDifficulty.setBounds(128, 336, 120, 80);
    jDifficulty.setBackground(new Color(0x666666));
    jDifficulty.setForeground(new Color(0x666666));
    jDifficultyRB0.setBounds(7, 18, 106, 20);
    jDifficultyRB0.setSelected(true);
    jDifficultyBG.add(jDifficultyRB0);
    jDifficulty.add(jDifficultyRB0);
    jDifficultyRB1.setBounds(7, 37, 106, 19);
    jDifficultyBG.add(jDifficultyRB1);
    jDifficulty.add(jDifficultyRB1);
    jDifficultyRB2.setBounds(7, 56, 106, 19);
    jDifficultyBG.add(jDifficultyRB2);
    jDifficulty.add(jDifficultyRB2);
    jDifficulty.setBorder(jDifficultyTB);
    cp.add(jDifficulty);
    jScrollPane2.setBounds(352, -16, 1, 17);
    cp.add(jScrollPane2);
    // Ende Komponenten
    
    setVisible(true);
  } // end of public JFrame2
  

  // Anfang Methoden
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JFrame2();
    
    
  } // end of main
  
  public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    SpiceWars4 jf1 = new SpiceWars4();  //initalisierung neues jframe
    jf1.setVisible(true);
    dispose();  //Schließt die Einstellungen
   
  } // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed
  
  public void jmute_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
      
  
    
  } // end of jmute_ActionPerformed
  
  public void bDarkMode1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    
    if (evt.getSource()==bDarkMode1) {
      jButton1.setBackground(new Color(0x49969E));
      jButton1.setForeground(new Color(0x333333));
      cp.setBackground(new Color(0x666666));
      jmute.setBackground(new Color(0x49969E));
      jDifficulty.setBackground(new Color(0x666666));
      jDifficulty.setForeground(new Color(0x666666));
     
    } // end of if
    
  } // end of bDarkMode1_ActionPerformed

  public void bLightMode1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Container cp = getContentPane();
    if (evt.getSource()==bLightMode1) {
      
      jButton1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      jButton1.setForeground(new Color(0x666666));
      jDifficulty.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      jmute.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      cp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      
    } // end of if
    
    
  } // end of bLightMode1_ActionPerformed

  public String jDifficultyBG_getSelectedButtonGroupLabel() {
    for (java.util.Enumeration<AbstractButton> e = jDifficultyBG.getElements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
      AbstractButton b = e.nextElement();
      if (b.isSelected()) return b.getText();
    }
    return "";
  }

  // Ende Methoden
} // end of class JFrame2
```

For Example, when the user clicks the LightMode button, it should apply to the main Jframe too, same with the DarkMode button.

Would be thankful for help, since I'm still a beginner.

Comment: An application should only have a single main JFrame. For the child window you can use a JDialog and specify the frame as the parent of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [observer pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern), when an event occurs somewhere you want your first JFrame to react to it.

**This solution requires Java 7 or later**

It would make sense to have a separate class maintain the state of your settings. This implementation is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which will work well enough for your implementation, although as you learn there will be better options.

```java
public class Settings {
   public enum ScreenMode {
      LIGHT,
      DARK
   }

   private static Settings settings;
   private ScreenMode screenMode = ScreenMode.LIGHT;
   private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

   /**
    * Private constructor to force singleton pattern
    */
   private Settings() {
      pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
   }

   /**
    * Get the singleton instance of Settings.
    * When you learn dependency injection, prefer that.
    */
   public static Settings getSettings() {
      if (settings == null) {
         settings = new Settings();
      }
      return settings;
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
      pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
   }

   public void setScreenMode(ScreenMode mode) {
      pcs.firePropertyChange("screen_mode", this.screenMode, mode);
      this.screenMode = mode;
   }
}
```

This settings object will allow any `PropertyChangeListener` to subscribe to it and be notified whenever a property changes. JFrame 1 can become a `PropertyChangeListener` by implementing the interface and subscribing to the `Settings.addPropertyChangeListener()` method.

```java
public class SpiceWars4 extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener {

   public SpiceWars4() { 
      // Frame-Initialisierung
      super();
      Settings.getSettings().addPropertyChangeListener(this); // Subscribe
      ...
   }

   ...

   @Override
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("screen_mode")) {
         Settings.ScreenMode mode = (Settings.ScreenMode) evt.getNewValue();
         switch (mode) {
            case LIGHT:
               // Called when screen mode is changed from dark to light
               break;
            case DARK:
               // Called when screen mode is changed from light to dark
               break;
         }
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Then the code from JFrame 2 that actually sets the property when you click the button:

```java
Settings.getSettings().setScreenMode(Settings.ScreenMode.DARK);
```

Setting the screen mode fires a property change event that will execute the `propertyChange(PropertyEvent)` method of all subscribers (JFrame 1). The event can then be handled or ignored as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried your solution, but unfortunately, it throws follwing error:  `SpiceWars4.java:209:31: error: cannot find symbol
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class PropertyChangeEvent
  location: class SpiceWars4
Note: SpiceWars4.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error`

Comment: @JonasOFF ensure you have the right import for the `PropertyChangeEvent` class, the import is `import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;`

Comment: Also nowadays I typically assume people are using Java 8 or later, which might be a bad assumption. The solution I offered requires Java 7 or later so if you are using an earlier version this will not work.